# Using the linq search option in enumerate files

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Quick one here. I am trying to `EnumerateFiles` in a C# application and I want to find all the files in a directory that do not match a given pattern. So I would have something like this:

```
 var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles("MY_DIR_PATH", "NOT_MY_FILE_NAME");
```

Can someone help me out with the **not** part?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think you can use that overload of EnumerateFiles for this, but you can use linq:

```
Directory.EnumerateFiles("MY_DIR_PATH").Where(s => s != "NOT_MY_FILE_NAME");
```

or in query syntax:

```
var files = from f in Directory.EnumerateFiles("MY_DIR_PATH")
            where f != "NOT_MY_FILE_NAME"
            select f;
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed to know, thanks (I'm a bit of a LINQ noob)

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like that:

```
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles("MY_DIR_PATH")
                     .Where(fileName => fileName != "MY_FILE_NAME");
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles("MY_DIR_PATH")
    .Where(f => !f.Contains("NOT_MY_FILE_NAME"));
```